# Releasing an object that can be [NSNull null] or not

Tags: ios, memory-management, null, crash

I have a memory management problem I can't get my head around on iOS. I'm getting data from a SQLite db where some cells can be empty. So to handle this case, I assign [NSNull null] to my recipient if empty, or the value if not:

```
NSString *email = (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6) == NULL ? [NSNull null] : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
```

But then if I do that:

```
[email release];
```

the analyser doesn't like it and I think it crashes my program when the object is actually [NSNull null].

So I've tried:

```
(id) email == [NSNull null] ? nil:[email release];
```

But it doesn't work (still crashes and analyser doesn't like it). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using in that case `nil` value. For example:

```
NSString *email = (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6) == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
```

In such case you can safely call `[email release]; // email can be NSString or nil` and all will work as you need.

Comment: Thanks, nil can indeed be release. However I found out that you can tell SQLite what values to put in an empty cell, so I just choose to put an empty string instead of the C NULL. Saves me some code!